# Can I authorize Google Drive from a PHP server?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I use the following code to get a google user to authorise an app so they can create a file on google drive.

```
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setClientId($client_id);
   $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
   $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
   $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
   $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```

Is there anyway for me to authorize my own google account from the server, so an end user then never has to authorize the app?

I want to display a google presenation doc within an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are two approaches you can take.

- Create a service account and share the presentation to the service account
- Use a regular account, storing a refresh token on the server and using that to generate an access token.

In both cases, a malicious user could use the access token to access any files of the server user, so make sure you use drive.file scope so the files exposed are limited to those created by, or shared with your app.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. Doesnt make sense. How would that server auth go to the client where its needed? If you send your own previously saved tokens to the user it would be a security concern.
You need to share the presentation by url so anyone can open it. No need for auth code.